# Pandas implode Dataframe with values separated by char

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I was just wondering how is the best approach to implode a DataFrame with values separated by a given char.

For example, imagine this dataframe:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   z   a   q   p   
2   x   s   w   l
3   c   d   e   k   
4   v   f   r   m
5   b   g   t   n
```

And we want to implode by `@`

```
A           B           C           D           E
1@2@3@4@5   z@x@c@v@b   a@s@d@f@g   q@w@e@r@t   p@l@k@m@n
```

Maybe to create a copy from the original dataframe and process column by column with Pandas str.concat?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) with `join`, then convert `Series` to one row `DataFrame` with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df.astype(str).agg('@'.join).to_frame().T
print (df)
           A          B          C          D          E
0  1@2@3@4@5  z@x@c@v@b  a@s@d@f@g  q@w@e@r@t  p@l@k@m@n
```